# format y-axis display to display values by increments of .2

Tags: javascript, flot

I would like to know how I can format the display of my y-axis, I want to format it in such a way that given a range of 15-20(of course! this will be dynamic, but for the sake of this example ill be using this) so the expected output would be:

```
`[15,15.2,15.4,15.6,15.8,16,16.2,16.4,16.6,16.8,17..and so on`]
```

Instead my output is like this:

```
[15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `tickSize` option for the y-axis:

```
yaxis: {
    ticksize: 0.2
}
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more information.